Singular matrix during B Spline interpolation
According to the literature about B Splines, including Wolfram Mathworld, the condition for Cox de Boor's recursive function states that:

In python, this would translate to:
if (d_ == 0):
   if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ < knots_[k_+1]):
      return 1.0
   return 0.0

where:

d_: degree of the curve
knots_: knot vector
k_: index of the knot
t_: parameter value {0.0,...,1.0} (reparametrized)

However, this seems to generate a Singular matrix, when creating the linear system intended for interpolation, not approximation. For example, with 4 points:
  A = [[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
       [0.2962963  0.44444444 0.22222222 0.03703704]
       [0.03703704 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.2962963 ]
       [0.         0.         0.         **0.**    ]] //The last element (bottom-right) should have been 1.0
  # Error: LinAlgError: file C:\Users\comevo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_linalg.py line 104: Singular matrix

If I change the second part of the condition to:
if (d_ == 0):
   if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ <= knots_[k_+1]): // using <= instead of <
      return 1.0
   return 0.0

I get the correct matrix and the correct spline.
A = [[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
     [0.2962963  0.44444444 0.22222222 0.03703704]
     [0.03703704 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.2962963 ]
     [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]] // OK

Why does the code need to deviate from the mathematical condition in order to get the correct results and the iterator reaching the last element?
See below the complete example code:
import numpy as np
import math
from geomdl import knotvector

def cox_de_boor( d_, t_, k_, knots_):
    if (d_ == 0):
        if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ <= knots_[k_+1]):
            return 1.0
        return 0.0
    
    denom_l = (knots_[k_+d_] - knots_[k_])
    left = 0.0    
    if (denom_l != 0.0):
        left = ((t_ - knots_[k_]) / denom_l) * cox_de_boor(d_-1, t_, k_, knots_)
    
    denom_r = (knots_[k_+d_+1] - knots_[k_+1])
    right = 0.0
    if (denom_r != 0.0):
        right = ((knots_[k_+d_+1] - t_) / denom_r) * cox_de_boor(d_-1, t_, k_+1, knots_)

    return left + right

def interpolate( d_, P_, n_, ts_, knots_ ):
    A = np.zeros((n_, n_))
    
    for i in range(n_):
        for j in range(n_):
            A[i, j] = cox_de_boor(d_, ts_[i], j, knots_)
    
    control_points = np.linalg.solve(A, P_)
    return control_points

def create_B_spline( d_, P_, t_, knots_):
    sum = MVector()
    for i in range( len(P_) ):
        sum += P_[i] * cox_de_boor(d_, t_, i, knots_)
    return sum
    
def B_spline( points_ ):
    d     = 3
    P     = np.array( points_ )
    n     = len( P )
    ts    = np.linspace( 0.0, 1.0, n )
    knots = knotvector.generate( d, n ) # len = n + d + 1
    
    control_points = interpolate( d, P, n, ts, knots)
    
    crv_pnts = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = float(i) / 9
        crv_pnts.append( create_B_spline(d, control_points, t, knots) )
    return crv_pnts


control_points = [ [float(i), math.sin(i), 0.0] for i in range(8) ]
cps = B_spline( control_points )

Result:


The  original code you had is correct knots_[k_] <= t_ < knots_[k_+1]. And it does lead to a singular matrix. This situation is usually handled via a special case. Solutions vary. For example adding another point (or 2 points) to the end of the curve to form a straight line along the curve tangent. (and not rendering past the last point of the original curve). I have also seen points put almost on top of each other. Or, matrix regularization such as adding a small epsilon to the zero value so the matrix is invertible. The solution the code you posted also can work.
